# Auto fill a windows desktop application login screen in .net

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is there a way to autofill a windows application login screen using .net?

Basicaly I want to simply have my user put their credentials into my application where I then launch this other program and put their credentials into the login window for them.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: More explanations please. SO we have 1 application or two? When should users put their credentials and when you will do for them?

Comment: You're going to need to get into window handlers and all those c++ stuff.

Comment: doesn't Petzold know windows already? ;)

Comment: No relation to Charles.... that I know of.

Comment: @ Aliostad: I have two applications. My application and the second one which I will be loging into for the my user. Once the user authenticates against me, I will use their stored credentials for the application I am opening for them and log them in.

Answer (score -1):

there are some APIs you can call can tp grab the window object and make subsequent calls to grab the handle of the textboxes within the window. once you have the handle you can call another API to set the text on it. here are some of the APIs im talking about:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=True)>
Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=True)>
Private Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=True)>
Private Shared Function DestroyWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr

<DllImport("user32", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True)>
Private Shared Function GetWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal uCmd As Integer) As IntPtr
End Function

Private Declare Function SetFocus Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
'Private Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As String) As Boolean
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As String) As IntPtr
End Function


Public Sub SetTitle(ByVal Title As String)
    Dim h As New HandleRef(Me, Handle)
    SendMessage(h, WM_SETTEXT, 0, Title)
End Sub

Public Function GetTitle() As String
    Dim str As String = String.Empty
    Dim h As New HandleRef(Me, Handle)
    SendMessage(h, WM_GETTEXT, 300, str)
    Return str
End Function
```